# scipy package import error

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have installed scipy on Mac. It imports perfectly fine, but is missing some libraries.
When I try loading diags it throws error:

```
from scipy.sparse import diags 
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name diags
```

The scipy version that I have is 0.10.1. How can I upgrade this?

Comment: `scipy.sparse.diags` was added in version 0.11 of scipy.

Comment: Thanks. How do I upgrade scipy in mac? Sorry for the naive question.

Comment: How did you install 0.10.1?

Comment: sudo port install py27-numpy py27-scipy py27-matplotlib py27-ipython +notebook py27-pandas py27-sympy py27-nose

Comment: I'm not sure what the latest recommended method is for installing scipy on a Mac, but a good option is to use one of the free python distributions, such as Enthought's Canopy (https://www.enthought.com/products/canopy/) or Continuum's Anaconda (https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/)

Comment: For what it's worth, this page http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=scipy makes it look like scipy 0.13.0 is available via macports.

Comment: Thanks @WarrenWeckesser. But the port install gets directed to py24-scipy --->  Computing dependencies for py-scipy
--->  Dependencies to be installed: py24-scipy
In short it doesn't work, perhaps I need to cleanup my exisiting installation.
Is there a way to clean up and reinstall afresh?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't used macports in years.

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade `scipy` using `pip`:

```
pip install scipy --upgrade
```